# Database connection works in node.js file but not in script tags

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mlab

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB database (or to the server actually MongoLab), it works fine when I have the code in `name.js` file but it doesn't work when I have it in HTML file inside `<script>` tags.

Also, I only have those 2 files in my folder, and I'm using Cloud9 framework.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
// JavaScript File
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "x";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mkndb");
  var myobj = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
  dbo.collection("test").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document inserted");
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: How are you building this app?

Comment: Mongo client is a node module and if i am not wrong, require not work on client side things like script tag,Because import things normally get converted to es5 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The package `mongodb` you are requiring is a node.js package, it runs only on the server side and not in the browser.

To access a MongoDB on the client side, you can use the REST webservice.
It allows rudimentary queries through `XmlHttpRequests`.

To enable it, you have to start mongod with the `--rest` parameter.
Then you can then query it like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:28017/someDatabase/someCollection/?filter_name=someFilter
```

Comment: Note that the web interfaces (rest, httpinterface and/or jsonp) are insecure. You should not use them in production. Also, you would not be able to use this option with mLab.

Comment: of course, for me accessing the database from your client directly is always insecure as it means that you distribute your credentials to all your users

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the Mongodb node client. Inserting the script in html page with  tags would not work in the same way as you expect. You have few ways to achieve what you are looking for :
1. You can build a nodejs server component which can handle the requests from browser application. The nodejs server then interacts with mongodb and respond. This again can be achieved in few ways. 
a. Deploy nodejs in Lambda. Mode details here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/lambda-functions.html . You can then connect from the browser as given here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/browser-invoke-lambda-function-example.html 
b. Deploy in EC2 
2. If you do not want to build/deploy the node.js server, try using the mLab Data API. (http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/) . This works only for this special case where you are trying to connect to MongoLab

Comment: Wanted to chime in to say you should be careful using the mLab data API in the browser. mLab strongly recommends using one of the MongoDB drivers (and creating your own API) to connect to your database instead of the data API. Your API key will give full access to all data within the databases belonging to your mLab account. So if you distribute it in client-side applications, people can gain access to your account and your data.

Comment: Will I don't think I'm able to use the mLap Data API since I want to use a count query. I've never worked with node js servers. Will I have the same code in the file?